# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, hotmail

I don't understand why i am getting this exception.
This is the code that attempts to send email message.

```
public void sendAsHotmail() {
    final String username = jTextField14.getText();
    final String password = jPasswordField4.getText();
    String subject = jTextField16.getText();
    String Cc = jTextField17.getText();
    String Bcc = jTextField18.getText();
    String recipient = jTextArea5.getText();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put( "mail.smtp.host" , "smtp.live.com");
    props.put( "mail.smtp.user" , username );

    // Use TLS
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth" , "true" );
    props.put( "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" , "true" );
    props.put( "mail.smtp.password" , password );

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance( props , new Authenticator() {
        @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  if( username == null | password == null ) 
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( new JFrame() , "username or password incorrect");
                  return new PasswordAuthentication( username , password );
                }
    });
    String to = recipient;
    String from = username + "@hotmail.com";
    String emailMessage = jTextArea2.getText();
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource( fileName );

    try {
        message.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse( to ) );
        message.setFrom( new InternetAddress(from) );
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText( emailMessage );
        attachment.setDataHandler( new DataHandler( fds ) );
        attachment.setFileName( fileName );
        messagePart.setText( emailMessage );
        Multipart hotmailMP = new MimeMultipart();
        hotmailMP.addBodyPart(attachment);
        hotmailMP.addBodyPart( messagePart );
        message.setContent( hotmailMP );
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.send(message);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame() , "mail sent !");       
    }  catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
}
```

Why do i get this exception ? If there is anything wrong with the code please tell what the problem is.

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @ Mi Mee .
In your username it seems you are taking the incomplete username *(That is the reason **Authentication failed**)*. For Hotmail you have to enter your **Windows Live Id** that could be `xyz@hotmail.com , qrs@gmail.com` *etc.*

So take in the correct username. And remove `@hotmail.com` from the `from` variable. Rest of the code is fine.

Comment: yeah! i didn't notice that thing

Answer (score 7):

535 means bad username or password: see [SMTP reply codes](http://www.supermailer.de/smtp_reply_codes.htm)

You might need to check your SMTP server's manual to see what 5.0.0 means.