# jenkins email-ext plugin stopped work

Tags: jenkins

I have unclear situation with email notification. When email triggering from job, I get  "MessagingException message: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful", but when I go to Manage jenkins -> configure system -> E-mail Notification, and run "Test configuration by sending test e-mail" I get "Email was successfully sent" and email to mail box. "E-mail Notification" and "Extended E-mail Notification" using the same SMTP server, and 2 days ago all working good. I'm at a loss... Any ideas, where to look for the problem? Thanks !

Update:

It seems problem precisely with email-ext plugin. Because, I added to my job two notifications section, first usual notification (Send e-mail for every unstable build) and second "Editable email notification", and I get a result: first notification successfuly sent, second says "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful". Two days ago I change password for email, and made changes to the jenkins settings. But it looks like email-ext plugin try authenticate with old password. May be somebody knows, how to reset plugin settings ?

Comment: This are similar threads with the same exception (however not exactly related to Jenkins) But its worth taking a look and see if it helps!   [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800561/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-0-0-authentication-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the plugin doesn't update settings...  It can be done manually, /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml , need update hash in `<smtpAuthPassword></smtpAuthPassword>` section.