# Sending an email from an android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, email

my app crashes whenever i open the page that contains this code

```kotlin
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
        main(arrayOf("myEmail@gmail.com","password1","myEmail@gmail.com","myEmail@gmail.com", "myEmail@gmail.com"))
        
        }
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val userName =  args[0]
        val password =  args[1]

        val emailFrom = args[2]
        val emailTo = args[3]
        val emailCC = args[4]

        val subject = "SMTP Test"
        val text = "Hello Kotlin Mail"

        val props = Properties()
        putIfMissing(props, "mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com")
        putIfMissing(props, "mail.smtp.port", "587")
        putIfMissing(props, "mail.smtp.auth", "true")
        putIfMissing(props, "mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")

        val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, object : javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                return PasswordAuthentication(userName, password)
            }
        })

        session.debug = true

        try {
            val mimeMessage = MimeMessage(session)
            mimeMessage.setFrom(InternetAddress(emailFrom))
            mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo, false))
            mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(emailCC, false))
            mimeMessage.setText(text)
            mimeMessage.subject = subject
            mimeMessage.sentDate = Date()

            val smtpTransport = session.getTransport("smtp")
            smtpTransport.connect()
            smtpTransport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.allRecipients)
            smtpTransport.close()
        } catch (messagingException: MessagingException) {
            messagingException.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun putIfMissing(props: Properties, key: String, value: String) {
        if (!props.containsKey(key)) {
            props[key] = value
        }
    }

}
```

Trying to make an app in kotlin that is able to send emails without opening an email app, above is my code. whenever i go to this page in the app it crashes, im not sure what to do, any ideas? the goal is to have automated emails send without user interaction, they will put in their information once and then after that all they have to do is hit send and it will generate information such as date and time and then it will send based on previously entered information.

this is the error stack trace provided by logcat:

```
 ---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (17141) for package com.example.myapplication ----------------------------
2023-06-12 14:46:20.090 17141-17141 ziparchive              com.example.myapplication            W  Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.myapplication/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dm': No such file or directory
2023-06-12 14:46:20.098 17141-17141 ziparchive              com.example.myapplication            W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~ElgGTbi-0GuD4FTf5MgSLg==/com.example.myapplication-D5fAv_4aBc46ggVTmpQXYg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-06-12 14:46:20.102 17141-17141 ziparchive              com.example.myapplication            W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~ElgGTbi-0GuD4FTf5MgSLg==/com.example.myapplication-D5fAv_4aBc46ggVTmpQXYg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-06-12 14:46:20.586 17141-17141 nativeloader            com.example.myapplication            D  Configuring clns-6 for other apk /data/app/~~ElgGTbi-0GuD4FTf5MgSLg==/com.example.myapplication-D5fAv_4aBc46ggVTmpQXYg==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~ElgGTbi-0GuD4FTf5MgSLg==/com.example.myapplication-D5fAv_4aBc46ggVTmpQXYg==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication
2023-06-12 14:46:20.663 17141-17141 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.myapplication            V  Currently set values for:
2023-06-12 14:46:20.665 17141-17141 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.myapplication            V    angle_gl_driver_selection_pkgs=[]
2023-06-12 14:46:20.666 17141-17141 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.myapplication            V    angle_gl_driver_selection_values=[]
2023-06-12 14:46:20.668 17141-17141 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.myapplication            V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.myapplication: false
2023-06-12 14:46:20.670 17141-17141 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.myapplication            V  com.example.myapplication is not listed in per-application setting
2023-06-12 14:46:20.671 17141-17141 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.myapplication            V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2023-06-12 14:46:21.063 17141-17173 libEGL                  com.example.myapplication            D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-06-12 14:46:21.076 17141-17173 libEGL                  com.example.myapplication            D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-06-12 14:46:21.115 17141-17173 libEGL                  com.example.myapplication            D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-06-12 14:46:21.416 17141-17141 AppCompatDelegate       com.example.myapplication            D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2023-06-12 14:46:21.821 17141-17141 e.myapplication         com.example.myapplication            W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-06-12 14:46:21.826 17141-17141 e.myapplication         com.example.myapplication            W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-06-12 14:46:22.230 17141-17141 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.myapplication            D  Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10184; state: ENABLED
2023-06-12 14:46:22.783 17141-17141 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.myapplication            D  Compat change id reported: 237531167; UID 10184; state: DISABLED
2023-06-12 14:46:22.787 17141-17141 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.myapplication            W  Unknown dataspace 0
2023-06-12 14:46:22.916 17141-17171 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.myapplication            W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2023-06-12 14:46:22.918 17141-17141 AutofillManager         com.example.myapplication            D  notifyViewEnteredForFillDialog:1073741824
2023-06-12 14:46:22.921 17141-17171 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.myapplication            W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2023-06-12 14:46:22.924 17141-17141 AutofillManager         com.example.myapplication            D  Triggering pre-emptive request for fill dialog.
2023-06-12 14:46:22.949 17141-17141 AutofillManager         com.example.myapplication            D  notifyViewEnteredForFillDialog:1073741825
2023-06-12 14:46:23.559 17141-17171 Gralloc4                com.example.myapplication            I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2023-06-12 14:46:23.616 17141-17171 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.myapplication            E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-06-12 14:46:23.846 17141-17141 Choreographer           com.example.myapplication            I  Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-06-12 14:46:23.875 17141-17141 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.myapplication            D  Compat change id reported: 163400105; UID 10184; state: ENABLED
2023-06-12 14:46:23.877 17141-17177 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.myapplication            I  Davey! duration=1035ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=126882, IntendedVsync=8948596577142, Vsync=8948596577142, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=8948603131000, AnimationStart=8948603283200, PerformTraversalsStart=8948603452900, DrawStart=8949415107000, FrameDeadline=8948613243808, FrameInterval=8948602987400, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=8949456775900, SyncStart=8949458121900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=8949461528900, SwapBuffers=8949627627500, FrameCompleted=8949633292400, DequeueBufferDuration=193600, QueueBufferDuration=2014400, GpuCompleted=8949631385600, SwapBuffersCompleted=8949633292400, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=8949627627500, 
2023-06-12 14:46:23.906 17141-17141 AssistStructure         com.example.myapplication            I  Flattened final assist data: 1820 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
2023-06-12 14:46:25.461 17141-17171 EGL_emulation           com.example.myapplication            D  app_time_stats: avg=268.99ms min=26.57ms max=1325.92ms count=6
2023-06-12 14:46:26.087 17141-17141 System.out              com.example.myapplication            I  DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0
2023-06-12 14:46:26.350 17141-17141 System.out              com.example.myapplication            I  DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
2023-06-12 14:46:26.414 17141-17141 AndroidRuntime          com.example.myapplication            D  Shutting down VM
2023-06-12 14:46:26.430 17141-17141 AndroidRuntime          com.example.myapplication            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 17141
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity2}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1675)
                                                                                                        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
                                                                                                        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
                                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
                                                                                                        at javax.mail.URLName.getHostAddress(URLName.java:520)
                                                                                                        at javax.mail.URLName.hashCode(URLName.java:496)
                                                                                                        at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:383)
                                                                                                        at javax.mail.Session.getPasswordAuthentication(Session.java:889)
                                                                                                        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:349)
                                                                                                        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
                                                                                                        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity2.main(MainActivity2.kt:87)
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.kt:24)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
2023-06-12 14:46:26.487 17141-17171 EGL_emulation           com.example.myapplication            D  app_time_stats: avg=19.01ms min=7.05ms max=67.51ms count=32
2023-06-12 14:46:26.550 17141-17141 Process                 com.example.myapplication            I  Sending signal. PID: 17141 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (17141) for package com.example.myapplication ----------------------------
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the error stacktrace?

Comment: i think i just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity2}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Basically, you cannot do network operations on the main (UI) thread, this is a policy to prevent the apps from ANRs (Application Not Responding, android will close an application if it does not respond to user interaction within 5 seconds!), you should handle networking "stuff" in a different thread, which makes the user experience a lot better (it would be weird if the app just... stopped for some time after you press a button)

This problem has already been covered in many posts, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297485/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-sending-an-email-from-android/18297516#18297516), but:

To fix your issue you could:

1. override this rule (BAD WAY, might cause crashes)
2. use a [runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/Runnable) or separate the network request to a viewModel function that uses the [viewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Also, make sure your AppManifest contains:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: so are you saying that i could just do something like this?

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
...
}
fun sendEmail(args: Array<String>) {
run{
...
}
}

and itd work?
sorry for bad formatting idk how to do it

Comment: No, that would still make it run in the main thread, if you really don't know anything about viewModel, scopes, runnables and threads you could use the [GlobalScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) (It's not recommended, but It probably would work) you can just wrap the network operation with `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {/*put your operation here (in your case, probably the try...catch block) */ }` and it should not crash (hopefully)

Comment: i can learn more about that stuff later, for now I want it to run. i put It in global scope and its not crashing now but its also not sending anything. any ideas? thank you for your help

Comment: You could check the logcat for logs

Comment: right you are, it says that authentication failed but I know that is the correct information. i also just had a thought, would two factor authentication mean this wouldn't work?
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3

Comment: This is basically a new question, so you should create a new post for it, but I feel like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6801337/15749574) might just solve your issue, update: yea, two factor auth might be a problem here also